# How can I keep table cells the same width?

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm currently working with a dynamic table that renders a list of items when you select them from the drop down menu.  The problem I'm having is that some items warp the width of the cells in the table, even though I specify a max-width to each of them.  This is obviously troubling when your headers don't match up for different lists.

I've never really had any issues creating tables like this before, but maybe there is something that I'm missing here.

Here's the method to render the table

```js
RenderTable(items){
        var rows = [];
        let itemList = this.state.ItemList;

        for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < itemList.length; j++){
                if(items[i].ID == itemList[j].ID){
                    rows.push(
                        <tr style={{backgroundColor: '#B7BCDF'}} id={items[i].ID} key={i}>
                            <td style={{maxWidth: '20px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} id={items[i].ID}>
                                {itemList[j].PartName}
                            </td>
        
                            <td  style={{maxWidth: '20px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} id={items[i].ID}>
                                {itemList[j].Description}
                            </td>
        
                            <td  style={{maxWidth: '20px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} id={items[i].ID}>
                                {itemList[j].Type}
                            </td>
        
                            <td  style={{maxWidth: '20px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} id={items[i].ID}>
                                {items[i].Quantity}
                            </td>
        
                            <td  style={{maxWidth: '20px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}} id={items[i].ID}>
                                {itemList[j].Units}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ) 
                }
            }     
        }
        return (

            <div className="TableScroll" style={{width: '74.5%'}}>
                <table className="TableRows">
                    <tbody>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        );
    }
```

Here's the html for this table

```js
<div className="ParTableContainer">
                    <table className="PartTableHeaderContainer" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={{width: '20%'}}>Part Name</th>
                                <th style={{width: '20%'}}>Description</th>
                                <th style={{width: '20%'}}>Type</th>
                                <th style={{width: '20%'}}>QTY</th>
                                <th style={{width: '20%'}}>U/M</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>

                {this.RenderTable(this.state.PartList)}
```

Here is my css file containing some of the styles

```js
.PartTableHeaderContainer{
    border: 2px solid var(--Blue);
    background-color: var(--Blue);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.TableRows{
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.TableRows tr:hover td{
    background-color: var(--AccentBlue);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ParTableContainer{
    width: 75%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}


.TableScroll{
    width: 1036px;
    height: 60%;
    border: 2px solid;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here's a few pictures of what I'm talking about

This one is how I think the table should turn out:
[image]

And then there's this one that is all over the place:
[image]

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `table-layout: fixed` on your `<table>` element (add it to `.PartTableHeaderContainer` and `.TableRow` class or merge tables as others suggested it).

For property explanation, see here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/table-layout/

> fixed: With this value, the table's layout ignores the content and
>   instead uses the table's width, any specified width of columns, and
>   border and cell spacing values. The column values used are based on
>   widths defined on columns or cells for the first row of the table.

also, remove inline styles from table elements and instead add them to `div` wrappers inside. like so:

```
 <td id={items[i].ID}>
    <div style={{overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>
        {items[i].Quantity}
    </div>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a two table, so you can have a fixed header and a scrollable content. You can use this code snippet as a sample on how to do it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fixed Header Table</title>
<style>
  .PartTableHeaderContainer th{
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .TableScroll td{
    width: 20%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="525">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table class="PartTableHeaderContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="500" >
         <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
          <th>Part Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>QTY</th>
          <th>U/M</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:520px; height:80px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="500" class="TableScroll">
          <tr>
            <td>Sample Part</td>
            <td>This is a sample part</td>
            <td>Sample Type</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>ft</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Sample Part</td>
              <td>This is a sample part</td>
              <td>Sample Type</td>
              <td>100</td>
              <td>ft</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Sample Part</td>
              <td>This is a sample part</td>
              <td>Sample Type</td>
              <td>100</td>
              <td>ft</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Sample Part</td>
              <td>This is a sample part</td>
              <td>Sample Type</td>
              <td>100</td>
              <td>ft</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Sample Part</td>
              <td>This is a sample part</td>
              <td>Sample Type</td>
              <td>100</td>
              <td>ft</td>
          </tr>
         </table>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can just use one table like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<style>
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}

table tbody
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
}

table {
    width: 445px;
    border-spacing: 1px;
}

th
{
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
td
{
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Part Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>QTY</th>
              <th>U/M</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Sample Part</td>
              <td>This is a sample part</td>
              <td>Sample Type</td>
              <td>100</td>
              <td>ft</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sample Part</td>
                <td>This is a sample part</td>
                <td>Sample Type</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>ft</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Sample Part</td>
                <td>This is a sample part</td>
                <td>Sample Type</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>ft</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Sample Part</td>
                <td>This is a sample part</td>
                <td>Sample Type</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>ft</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sample Part</td>
                <td>This is a sample part</td>
                <td>Sample Type</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>ft</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you have to tables down there, why not putting all in one table?

```
      <table className="PartTableHeaderContainer" style{{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style={{width: '20%'}}>Part Name</th>
                            <th style={{width: '20%'}}>Description</th>
                            <th style={{width: '20%'}}>Type</th>
                            <th style={{width: '20%'}}>QTY</th>
                            <th style={{width: '20%'}}>U/M</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {rows}
                    </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: In this example I would just put {this.RenderTable()} inside the tbody?

Comment: yes exactly, maybe the problem is that there are two different tables, try it

Comment: Yeah this didn't work well at all lol.  Everything got squished and all the cells became one when I did this.